Bitbucket 7.21 Edit file API is not working as expected
Bitbucket 7.21 Edit file PUT API is not working as mentioned in official documentation.
Seems works as GET method.
url
/api/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/browse/{path}
Request payload
{
    "branch": "testing-branch",
    "content": "new content of read file",
    "message": "initial commit"
}

I tried PUT method and saw working as GET method.
Unable to see any new Commit after api call
